# jQuery - Slide div out and down from under another div when user enters something into an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to slide a div down from underneath another div when a user types something into a div.

---

I have tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZFMJ/2/) but I need it to slide down when the user types something in an input box.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<div id="search-container">
    <input type="text" name="search-input" id="search-input" placeholder="&#128270; type to search...">
</div>
```

**The div to slide down from underneath `search-container`**

```
<div class="container" id="search-result-container" class="hidestuff" >
```

**Some JS in the div `search-result-container` that might be usefull**

```
    <script>
     $('#search-result-container').hide();
     $('#search-input')
    .on('keyup', function(e) {
    var input = $(this).val();
    input.length ?
      $('#search-result-container').show() :
      $('#search-result-container').hide();

  })
    </script>
```

Any Ideas on how this could be achieved?
Many Thanks

Comment: Can you share a working code snippet demonstrating the issue?

Comment: You could probably use JQuery's animate()

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to JQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.slide<Down/Up>()` method could be useful here

```js
$('#search-input').on('input', function(e) {
  var input = $.trim( this.value );
  if ( input.length > 0 )
    $('#search-result-container').stop().slideDown();
  else
    $('#search-result-container').stop().slideUp();
});
```

```css
.hidestuff {
  display: none;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<div id="search-container">
  <input type="text" name="search-input" id="search-input" placeholder="&#128270; type to search...">
</div>
<div class="container hidestuff" id="search-result-container">
  Some JS in the div search-result-container that might be usefull
</div>
```

Pro tips:

- Use the `"input"` Event to register any kind of input change (like *paste* etc)
- Don't use two `class="" class=""` since only the first will apply
- Use jQuery's `$.trim()` to remove wrapping whitespaces

Comment: This works perfectly apart from when I type in something random and it says `no search results` but the div stays the same size as it was before.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Do: `if ( input.length > 0 && results.length > 0 )` where `results` is your array of results.

Comment: I don't think I have an array of results.